# Windows Server 2008R2 RDweb - connecting to PC's, multiple authentication prompts

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server running that's running the Remote Desktop Web Access role and Remote Desktop Gateway.

The web access is supposed to be used to connect to PC's in the internal network. I managed to get that to work, but I'm getting a lot of authentication prompts:

1. To connect to RDweb itself (that's OK)
   After selecting the "Remote Desktop" tab and filling in the computer name:
2. To connect to the Remote Desktop Gateway
3. To connect to the computer filled in in step 1

I would like to reduce that number to 2, if possible, 1. I have read a lot of articles regarding RDweb & single sign on, but they don't fix my problem. My case seems to be different:

1. I'm using RDweb to connect to computers ("Remote Desktop" tab), not RemoteApps
2. The computers connecting are not joined to the domain (they are external PC's)

It's not immediately obvious to me when going through all the remote desktop server options how I would go about fixing this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: In your Remote Desktop client, if you go to the Advanced tab, click the Connect from anywhere Settings button, where you set your RD Gateway address. If you check the box that says "Use my RD Gateway credentials for the remote computer," does that help?

Comment: If your computers are not in a domain, your life is going to be painful.  I believe you are mostly out of luck.   Windows solutions are very heavily biased towards the assumption that you will be setting up a Domain.

Comment: The destination computers are all in the domain, just the client connecting to the RDweb website may not be.

Comment: @RyanRies yes that does help, but I'm not using the remote desktop client (mstsc.exe), but RDweb (http://server.example.com/RDweb)